# Bitcoin node synchronization speed up

Tags: bitcoind, synchronization

I'm running [a docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/kylemanna/bitcoind/) with a bitcoin node (version v0.16.3.0-g49e34e288) and it's taking more than week to synchronize, having only synchronized 54% of the blockchain. I'm running it with the "prune=550" and "disablewallet" options. I there any way to speed up the synchronization process?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The pruning works after full node synchronized only !!!!
You can set it prune=550 only after that you have full node.
Full node, then type prune=550 in conf file, then shutdown, then restart.
Hi.

Comment: That is completely incorrect. You do not need to be fully synced before you can prune. Pruning is done on the fly and can be enabled on first start.